# SignalR - very slow to invoke hub from WPF app

Tags: asp.net, wpf, http, signalr

I have an ASP.NET WebForms application that has a number of SignalR hubs, that will be invoked from a WPF application. Initially I tested this via a console app rather than a WPF application, just to prove the concept. This was brilliant and was instantaneous.

Recently I have started to invoke the hub in the WPF app, using the exact same code, and I'm having a lot of speed issues (both when invoking locally and remotely) - the connection.Start().Wait() call can take up to 30 seconds!

Are there any clear reasons why connecting to a http url in WPF could be slow? My code for invoking is below. I have tried performing the invoking in a seperate thread but that did not help.

```
 private static void Execute(string hubName, List<KeyValuePair<string,object[]>> items)
    {
            FBDBDataContext dc = new FBDBDataContext();
            string url = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["WebURL"]; 
            var connection = new HubConnection(url);
            IHubProxy myHub = connection.CreateHubProxy(hubName);

            connection.Start().Wait(); // not sure if you need this if you are simply posting to the hub

            foreach (var kvp in items)
                myHub.Invoke(kvp.Key, kvp.Value);
    }
```

Comment: Try tracing the connection to see if that yields any more info as to why SignalR is taking 30 seconds to connect. You can trace directly to the console like so: `connection.TraceWriter = Console.Out;`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't be creating a new connection every time you wish to communicate with the server. Create it once at the start of the program and reuse it.

Comment: Brilliant, I've adapted my code to store the connection and now it's instant again! Thanks